# Difference between 3 values of 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, comparison

I have 2 tables like

```
id  att1 att2
1   34    56
2   45    12
3   34    11


id  att1 att2
1   14    10
2   25    2
3   14    10
```

How to get the diference between the 3 values like

```
id      att1      att2
1-1=0  34-14=20  56-10=46
2-2=0  45-25=20  12-2 =10  
3-3=0  34-14=20  11-10=1 


SELECT A.id-B.id, A.att1-B.att1,A.att2-B.att2 from TABLEA as A join TABLEB as B...
```

Comment: These two tables should have at least one matching column, otherwise, how to?

Comment: the ID I will use, but How to complete the query

Comment: Then check @John Pick answer. It should be fine that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for that you didn't already supply in your question. Did you mean something like this?

```
SELECT
    CAST(A.id AS VARCHAR(200)) + '-' +  CAST(B.id AS VARCHAR(200)) + '=' + CAST(A.id - B.id AS VARCHAR(200)) id
    ,CAST(A.att1 AS VARCHAR(200)) + '-' +  CAST(B.att1 AS VARCHAR(200)) + '=' + CAST(A.att1 - B.att1 AS VARCHAR(200)) att1
    ,CAST(A.att2 AS VARCHAR(200)) + '-' +  CAST(B.att2 AS VARCHAR(200)) + '=' + CAST(A.att2 - B.att2 AS VARCHAR(200)) att2
FROM
    TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want to subtract one id from another, do you?

```
SELECT
  A.id,
  A.att1 - B.att1,
  A.att2 - B.att2
FROM
  A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
```